# Require Condition for sitecollection not present with a value in array powershell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I am having an array containing 4 site collections, in that I need to check a condition that if a site collection " " is not present or doest contain a value in that array it should go in the loop.

I have tried by passing that array in a for loop and assigning it to a variable for retrieving each values from array. My condition is not working. Instead of using notcontains from the below code, is there any option to make conditon work?(Requirement is sitecollection should not contain a value in that array).

**Below is the code I use :**

`if(Site.Url.Notcontains($var)){}.`

But this is not working. How to write code instead of NotContains
 thanks

Comment: can you please provide us the entrie code in which you are working on.?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `if ($var)` for checking `null` or empty objects in PowerShell.

Example:

```
if($var)
{
    #The variable exists and is not null
}
else
{
    #The variable does not exist or is null
}
```

Comment: The question is how to check NOT NULL here actually

Comment: Well, if ($var) is true that means it is NOT NULL or NOT EMPTY

Comment: Added an example code to clarify :)

Answer (score 0):

you can check for contains and then checking not inside the if condition

```
 if(!Site.Url.Contains(" "))
```